# How I can define and appended an element to an array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, plist

I am working on a project which it reads a plist contains rows of dictionaries and an array named countries contains country, The countries array is filled with the data of my plist and all works fine, Now I need to define an element and use it to append to my array ,

Here is my country definition

```
struct Country : Codable {
    let orFlagEmoji, destFlagEmoji, : String

    private enum CointryKeys : String, CodingKey { case orFlagEmoji,destFlagEmoji }
}

var countries = [Country]()

 override func viewDidLoad() 
 {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     let urlPlist = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ListinFirstPage", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: urlPlist)


    do
    {
        countries = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle error
        print(error)
    }


    //The problem is in two line bottom 

    var test = [TableViewController.Country(orFlagEmoji: "something", destFlagEmoji: "one thing")]



    countries.append(test)




 }
```

and when I add this two lines

```
var test = [TableViewController.Country(orFlagEmoji: "something", destFlagEmoji: "one thing")]

countries.append(test)
```

It confronts this error 
`Cannot convert value of type '[TableViewController.Country]' to expected argument type 'TableViewController.Country'`
, I really appreciate for any help. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the brackets around `test`:

```swift
var test = TableViewController.Country(orFlagEmoji: "something", destFlagEmoji: "one thing")

countries.append(test)
```

Or, if you need to concatenate two arrays, do something along the lines of:

```swift
var test = [TableViewController.Country(orFlagEmoji: "something", destFlagEmoji: "one thing")]

countries += test
```

Comment: Yes , Thank you very much, It works , Really Really thank you David